# Does Vaadin provide realtime charting?

Tags: java, charts, real-time, vaadin, kpi

I want to plug in some realtime charts in my Vaadin application. I searched through the Vaadin sampler and addons and I was not able to find any. Are there any addons that are available that can provide real time charting (something like a continuous line graph, a counter)?

Comment: What do you mean by real time?
You can update your chart data on server side and this then updates the chart/graph on the client. You can either use the brandnew server push with vaadin 7.1 or one of the poll-methods in previous vaadin versions.

Comment: would push type method be scalable for real time applications (1 sec update interval)? What happens if there are lot of connections to the server

Comment: This depends on the number of clients, bandwidth to the clients and the "size" of the changeset to be sent to clients every second.

Comment: @amrk7 Vaadin Charts should support pushing to a surprisingly large number of chart objects and users. On YouTube, watch the [Vaadin Charts Webinar 2014](http://youtu.be/sKVczrmTa9M) to learn about the efficiencies of their architecture where Vaadin's server-side data combines with the built-in embedded JavaScript engine ([Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com)) doing all the drawing on the client-side.

Answer (score 2):

## Vaadin Charts

[Vaadin Charts](https://vaadin.com/add-ons/charts) is a very nice add-on to do just that, including live updating. Version 2 [arrived 2014-12](https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/vaadin-charts-2-0-released).

There is a free 30-day trial but after that you have to buy a license. If you're looking for something completely free, I'm afraid you have to do the integration yourself and then you could probably use most javascript charting libraries.

See [this live demo](http://demo.vaadin.com/charts/#SplineUpdatingEachSecond) of a line chart updating each second with random data. No complicated tricks involved; simply use the new [Push features in Vaadin 7](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/advanced.push.html) to have any server-side updates to the chart data automatically pushed to the client-side.

For more info, see [The Book Of Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/charts.html).

Comment: I looked at it.. But does it provide any real time charting like a continuous line graph for eg  (updates as and when the data is updated and again if it is going to be a push model would it be scalable?)

Comment: You can add the refresher addon which the polls the server verey X ms for changes and updates the chart. https://vaadin.com/de/directory#addon/refresher:vaadin.
Push/Pull models scalability depends on many factors, (number of clients, bandwidth, size of changesets, memory of server, etc.)

Comment: **UPDATE** With Vaadin 7 and current versions of Tomcat/Jetty and such, you can use the new built-in Push features with the `@Push` annotation to achieve real-time updating. No longer need that refresher add-on.